# Why is the electrostatic energy of a nucleus proportional to $Z(Z-1)$?

Tags: electrostatics, nuclear-physics, coulombs-law

The complete binding energy is (more details in Krane's book, page 68):

$$B = a_v A - a_s A^{2/3} - a_c Z(Z-1)A^{-1/3} - a_{sym} \frac{(A-2Z)^2}{A} + \delta$$

I want to explain the $Z(Z-1)$ term. After reading the book I thought I got the reason (from Krane):

> Our binding energy formula must also include the **Coulomb repulsion of the
>   protons**, which likewise tends to make the nucleus less tightly bound. Since each
>   proton repels all of the others, this term is proportional to $Z(Z-1)$.

Then, in the book,  the factor $Z(Z-1)$ is used to calculate the energy needed to charge a homogeneously charged sphere with radius $R$ and charge $Ze$:

$$-\frac{3}{5}\frac{Z^2 e^2}{4 \pi \epsilon R} \propto -\frac{Z^2}{R}$$

Where the negative sign implies a reduction in binding energy.

Then it is clear; $Z(Z-1)$ accounts for the Coulomb's repulsion force between the protons.

However, in the lecture my professor argued that accounts for the subtracted energy used to *build up* the nucleus (I literally copied this sentence really quick, so I may have copied it wrongly).

**Then, how can we argue** $Z(Z-1)$ **in terms of energy?** I think we could argue this repulsion in terms of Coulomb's potential.

Comment: "*build up* the proton"  Do you mean nucleus? How do you build up a proton?  I don't understand what's bothering you because $Z(Z-1) A^{-1/3}$ has all the particle terms and $a_c$ has all the constants buried inside ($e^2,\pi,\epsilon$, shielding factors, etc).

Comment: Ups I meant the nucleus, my bad. What is bothering me is how to explain $Z(Z-1)$ in terms of energy

Comment: *The complete binding energy is* This is the liquid drop energy, which is only an approximation to the actual binding energy. You probably also want to say here that this is the binding energy of *a nucleus.*

Comment: @JD_PM: When someone points out a mistake in the question, you should just edit the question to correct it.

Comment: @JD_PM It IS a repulsion factor because it reduces the binding energy.  High binding energy means more tightly bound.  A negative contribution to BE means something is making the system less bound.  Or are you asking how z(z-1) could have energy units?

Comment: @BillN I understand what Ben Crowell states; it is a mathematical factor. However, my teacher argued $Z(Z-1)$ in terms of energy. Thus I am still wondering why does it have energy units. Do you know why?

Comment: @JD_PM As I implied in my first comment, while $Z(Z-1)$ accounts for the interacting pairs of protons, there is also an $A^{-1/3}$ term which relates to the size of the nucleus, and hence is proportional to 1/R. The $a_c$ is an empirical factor which will absorb all the $e, \pi, \epsilon$ terms as well as account for the non-exactness of the 1/r term, and is the proportionality factor to make it all work out to energy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number of combinations of $Z$ things, taken 2 at a time and ignoring order, is $Z(Z-1)/2$. Therefore the number of interacting pairs of protons is proportional to $Z(Z-1)$.

Comment: And the $A^{-1/3}$ mimics the inverse distance factor.